# Time complexity with respect to input

Tags: time-complexity

This is a constant doubt I'm having. For example, I have a 2-d array of size n^2 (n being the number of rows and columns). Suppose I want to print all the elements of the 2-d array. When I calculate the time complexity of the algorithm with respect to n it's O(n^2 ). But if I calculated the time with respect to the input size (n^2 ) it's linear. Are both these calculations correct? If so, why do people only use O(n^2 ) everywhere regarding 2-d arrays?

Answer (score 0):

That is not how time complexity works. You cannot do "simple math" like that.

A two-dimensional square array of extent `x` has `n = x*x` elements. Printing these `n` elements takes `n` operations (or `n/m` if you print `m` items at a time), which is `O(N)`. The necessary work increases *linearly* with the number of elements (which is, incidentially, quadratic in respect of the array extent -- but if you arranged the same number of items in a 4-dimensional array, would it be any different? Obviously, no. That doesn't magically make it `O(N^4)`).

What you use time complexity for is not stuff like that anyway. What you want time complexity to tell you is an approximate idea of how some particular algorithm may change its behavior if you grow the number of inputs beyond some limit.

So, what you want to know is, if you do XYZ on one million items or on *two* million items, will it take approximately *twice as long*, or will it take approximately *sixteen times as long*, for example.

Time complexity analysis is irrespective of "small details" such as how much time an actual operations takes. Which tends to make the whole thing more and more academic and practically useless in modern architectures because constant factors (such as memory latency or bus latency, cache misses, faults, access times, etc.) play an ever-increasing role as they stay mostly the same over decades while the actual cost-per-step (instruction throughput, ALU power, whatever) goes down steadily with every new computer generation.

In practice, it happens quite often that the dumb, linear, brute force approach is faster than a "better" approach with better time complexity simply because the constant factor dominates everything.